# Bash - using variables in yad form combo box

Tags: bash, forms, variables, yad

Bash variables in Yad.

The yad '!' field separator is not separating the fields.

After researching other questions the yad man page and other yad resources, this has me stumped.

I am trying to use variables in a yad form combo box.

The variables are read from a list (cam_list) - in this case two camera models are listed, each followed by nine parameters - (not set in this case and not important to the question)

```
450D 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
N3300 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Variables $cam1 and $cam2 are declared as follows - the 1st and 11th entries in the text file.

```
cam1=$(awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $1 }' $cam_list)
cam2=$(awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $11 }' $cam_list)
```

Check variables

```
 echo $cam1 $cam2
 450D N3300
```

Put $cam1 and $cam2 into yad form fields

```
yad --form --center --text="test" \
                --field="Camera":CB \
                    "$cam1!$cam2"
```

[yad output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxHB0.png)

Or this way

```
"$cam1"!"$cam2"
```

Same result

Further enclosing the variables in double quotes shows $cam1 only...

```
""$cam1"!"$cam2""
```

[yad output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfANC.png)

The behaviour is the same with check boxes. For example;

```
yad --form --center --title="$TITLE" \
        --text="Please select a camera" \
        --field="$cam1":CHK \
            'TRUE!FALSE' \
        --field="$cam2":CHK \
            'TRUE!FALSE'
```

Not enough reputation to post a third image, but the expanded variables are grouped to a single check box, while the second check box is not associated with a variable - weird.

This was a headache but it works - the variables expand correctly

```
--field="ImageMagick threads":NUM \
            "$defaultcores"!1.."$CORES"!1!0 \
```

I'm not sure whether this is a yad issue or my application. I have a raft of yad dialogs and a paned notebook (6 tabs) that works well, in the same bash script.

Answer (score 1):

> VAR1='test1!test2!test3' ANS=$(yad --form --field="combo1:CBE"
>   'test1!test2!test3' \
>   --field="no-edit combo:CB" 'test1!test2!test3' \
>   --field="combo2:CBE" "$VAR1" )
>
> selected=$(echo $ANS | awk ' { print $1 $2 $3 }' | tr '|' "\n")
>   echo $selected

The use of single quotes is necessary when the string contains ! as
otherwise yad would treat it differently than for a field separator.

I know I am not using your $cam1 and $cam2 var as it is too advanced
for me, but at least I can assure you my example works and might trigger
a 'WOW' moment for your problem (only kidding!)

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

> Check variables
>
> ```
> echo $cam1 $cam2
> 450D N3300
> ```

You see, if you check them individually you will get this:

```
echo $cam1
450D N3300
echo $cam2
```

That is, `$cam1` contains "450D\nN3300\n" and `$cam2` contains "". In both cases `$1` is the first field of the file, and `$11` is... nothing. If you want to use awk for this then you need to check `NR` in the condition.

```
cam1=$(awk 'NR==1 { print $1 }' "$cam_list")
cam2=$(awk 'NR==2 { print $1 }' "$cam_list")
```

Comment: I see the error. All the lists and log files in use are single continuous lines. The cam_list is separate line entries. Which didn't occur to me until you pointed out the error.